# How to convert a method to async?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

tell me how to convert the method into async ?

```
 [HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel> customers =
        _customerRepository.GetAllCustomers().Select(s => new CustomerViewModel
        {
            CustomerId = s.CustomerId,
            Name = s.Name,
            Adress = s.Adress
        });
    return View("Index", customers);
}
```

Like this?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
```

Comment: Create a `GetAllCustomersAsync` then you can use await on this method

Comment: To get a fully working example, you'll have to provide code of GetAllCustomers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new async method

```
public interface ICustomerRepository
{
   // add async method to your interface
   Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> GetAllCustomersAsync();
}

public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
  // implementation here
  public async Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> GetAllCustomersAsync()
  {
     return await context.Customer.ToListAsync(); 
  }

}
```

Now in your async action

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    IEnumerable<Customer> customers =
        await _customerRepository.GetAllCustomersAsync();
    IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel> customersViewModel = customers.Select(s 
         => new CustomerViewModel
        {
            CustomerId = s.CustomerId,
            Name = s.Name,
            Adress = s.Adress
        });
    return View("Index", customersViewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I remade the GetAllCustomers method

```
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAllCustomers() 
    { 
        return _db.Customers; 
    }
```

The GetAllCustomers method, is implementation of the interface:

```
    public interface ICustomerRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<Customer> GetAllCustomers(); 
    }
```

**After I remade the GetAllCustomersAsync method as you specified the interface specified a mistake:**
'CustomerRepository' does not implement interface member 'ICustomerRepository.GetAllCustomers()'. 'CustomerRepository.GetAllCustomers()' cannot implement 'ICustomerRepository.GetAllCustomers()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'IEnumerable'.

Comment: [Stack overflow is not a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums).  You shouldn't not attempt to reply to an answer via an answer.  Instead you should use a comment.  If you have problems, you are always welcome to update/change your question.

Comment: You need to change the interface method too, as per Hasta's instruction to `Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> GetAllCustomersAsync();` and your repo method  is then `public async Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> GetAllCustomersAsync() 
    { 
        return await _db.Customers.ToListAsync(); 
    } `